# New user account login issues in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2014 locally on my machine. Windows did an update and somehow my user account got corrupted. I created a new user account on my machine with admin privileges and SQL Server automatically added the new user account as a sys admin. I found this out when I logged onto SSMS with my old windows account. I also noticed that the new user account was added with a SQL Server authentication. I would like the new account to have Windows authentication but somehow that is grayed out. Does any one know why? Also, when I try to login with my new account and SQL Server Authentication, I am getting a "Can not connect to local error"

Answer (score 1):

When you created the new account on your machine it was not created as an AD account.  It was most likely created as a local user account on your machine.  Since it is not tied to an AD Account, Windows Authentication is not an option as Active Directory is a requirement.

Comment: Is there a way to make it an AD account?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I just had to create another system admin account for myself with the new windows account and use that to log in.